# parseInt fails in certain strict comparisons ( stringParsedToInteger === 3; // returns undefined)

Tags: javascript, undefined, parseint

Just curious:

My code works if I compare a number string (e.g. '10') to an integer (10), using the comparison operator `==`.

But if I convert the string to an integer with `parseInt()` and compare to integers with the strict comparison operator `===` it fails – not immediately – once you start messing with the parameters (select menus).

The same code will work as expected without parseInt() and with comparison operators as in `(time == 5)`.

Code that fails:

```js
  const productSelect = document.querySelector('#product')
  let productValue = document.querySelector('#product').value
  const prodTimeSelect = document.querySelector('#prodTime')
  let prodTime = parseInt(document.querySelector('#prodTime').value)
  const text = document.querySelector('.textoutput')
 
  // Find start cost
  let findStartCost = function(time) {
    if (time === 5) {
      return startCost = 2000
    } else if (time === 10) {
      return startCost = 1500
    } else if (time === 20) {
      return startCost = 1000
    }
  }
  
  text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`

  // Update text if product changes
  productSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    productValue = e.target.value
    text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`
  })

  // Update text if production time changes
  prodTimeSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    prodTime = e.target.value
    text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`
  })
```

```html
<h3>Select Product</h3>
  <select id="product">
    <option value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
    <option value="4">Product 4</option>
    <option value="5">Product 5</option>
  </select>

  <h3>Select production time</h3>
    <select id="prodTime">
      <option value="5" selected="selected">5 days</option>
      <option value="10">10 days</option>
      <option value="20">20 days</option>
    </select>

<p class="textoutput"></p>
```

Code that works:

```js
const productSelect = document.querySelector('#product')
let productValue = document.querySelector('#product').value
const prodTimeSelect = document.querySelector('#prodTime')
let prodTime = document.querySelector('#prodTime').value
const text = document.querySelector('.textoutput')
 
// Find start cost
let findStartCost = function(time) {
  if (time == 5) {
   return startCost = 2000
  } else if (time == 10) {
   return startCost = 1500
  } else if (time == 20) {
   return startCost = 1000
 }
   }
  
text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`

// Update text if product changes
productSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
 productValue = e.target.value
 text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`
  })

// Update text if production time changes
  prodTimeSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
prodTime = e.target.value
text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`
  })
```

```html
<h3>Select Product</h3>
      <select id="product">
        <option value="1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="2">Product 2</option>
        <option value="3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="5">Product 5</option>
      </select>

      <h3>Select production time</h3>
        <select id="prodTime">
          <option value="5" selected="selected">5 days</option>
          <option value="10">10 days</option>
          <option value="20">20 days</option>
        </select>

    <p class="textoutput"></p>
```

Comment: You only assign to `description` once, on pageload - it never changes, so the text in the HTML never changes. Nothing to do with parseInt

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you, my bad, I have updated the code to reflect working and non-working JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the listener, when you do

```
prodTime = e.target.value
```

This retrieves the changed value, but the `.value` of an HTMLElement will always be a string. So when you pass that string to `findStartCost` with `findStartCost(prodTime)`, your conditions:

```
if (time === 5) {
  return startCost = 2000
} else if (time === 10) {
  return startCost = 1500
} else if (time === 20) {
  return startCost = 1000
}
```

always fail because the parameter `time` is always a string, not a number, so it'll never be `===` to a number.

`==`, in contrast, implicitly casts its operands when comparing, but it's unpredictable if you haven't memorized all the different possibilities, so it shouldn't be used.

Use `===` and explicitly cast the values yourself:

```
  prodTimeSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    prodTime = Number(e.target.value);
    text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`;
  })
```

Also, better not to implicitly create global variables - there's no need for a `startCost` variable, you can just return the plain value in `findStartCost`.

You may also make the code less repetitive by having just a single function that retrieves the values from the selects and populates the text.

```js
const productSelect = document.querySelector('#product');
const prodTimeSelect = document.querySelector('#prodTime');
const text = document.querySelector('.textoutput');

// Find start cost
let findStartCost = function(time) {
  if (time === 5) {
    return 2000;
  } else if (time === 10) {
    return 1500;
  } else if (time === 20) {
    return 1000;
  }
}

const updateText = () => {
  const productValue = productSelect.value;
  const prodTime = Number(prodTimeSelect.value);
  text.textContent = `The product number is #${productValue} and the production time is ${prodTime} days. Includes a start cost of ${findStartCost(prodTime)}.`;
};
updateText();
productSelect.addEventListener('change', updateText);
prodTimeSelect.addEventListener('change', updateText);
```

```html
<h3>Select Product</h3>
<select id="product">
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3</option>
  <option value="4">Product 4</option>
  <option value="5">Product 5</option>
</select>

<h3>Select production time</h3>
<select id="prodTime">
  <option value="5" selected="selected">5 days</option>
  <option value="10">10 days</option>
  <option value="20">20 days</option>
</select>

<p class="textoutput"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. The follow-up question: Why does it return 2000 when first loaded? The comparison of a string ` === ` integer shouldn't work under any circumstances?

Comment: On pageload, you do `let prodTime = parseInt(...`, so it's a number, not a string.

Comment: Though, when you just want to turn a non-number into a number, probably better to use Number than [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description), to avoid problems with radicies